Conditional update
I would like to create a conditional update on an audit table, such that if the update on the main table succeeds, then the update on the audit table is performed.
Right now I have this
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateParent`(
    IN inId INT(10), 
    IN inName varchar(75), 
    IN inEmail varchar(50), 
    IN inPhone varchar(8),
    IN inUsername varchar(50)
)
BEGIN

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION;

    update parent
    set nameOfPerson = inName
              ,email = inEmail 
              ,phonenr = inPhone
    where id = inId;
    
COMMIT;           
    
    SET @rowcount = ROW_COUNT();
    
    IF @rowcount > 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO parent_h
        (`parent_id`, `nameOfPerson`, `email`, `phonenr`, `opts`, `event`, `username`)
        SELECT id, nameOfPerson, email, phonenr, ts, "U", inUsername
        from parent
        where id = inId;        
    END IF;
    
        
COMMIT;       
    
END

Occasionally, if the update is performed and zero rows are updated (no data was changed), then I do not want the audit table update to be performed.
Are there any disadvantages of doing it this way? and are there any better ways? This is a web-application.

Put the INSERT in the same transaction as the UPDATE.

There is a disadvantage in this approach: what if you change parent table not by this stored procedure but by other means? Another stored procedure or even direct update statement?
The better solution would be to have a trigger on the main table which would copy data into audit one. Then your logic in this SP would be more simple and you would be sure that audit table is updated properly.
Also, do not do transaction control inside the SP. It is not needed in this particular instance. What is the point of starting transaction if you not expecting to roll it back?

The point of the transaction is to ensure transaction isolation. Is it possible to move the same logic to a trigger function? ie. the check for number of updated rows.

Also, will the trigger activate if zero rows were updated?

The reason why I had both updates in the same SP, is that the inUsername parameter is used in the audit table update, but not in the mail table update. Unless it is possible to pass parameters to the trigger, then this may not be the way forward.
